# Send URL Parameters to Google Sheet on Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to Send URL Parameters to a Google Sheet as soon as the page is loaded,

If I have a URL like, https://example.com/test?param1=value&param2=another

How could I get the data "value" and "another" added to a google sheet on load?

I am currently using the Form to Google Sheets Demo as published on GitHub here:

https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets

My current code is prefilling the text inputs, but it requires the user to press submit, instead I would like it to all happen without the need for any action from the user.

How would I do that?

I have explored many ways of auto-submitting forms on page load, but none of these have worked.

However is that the best path to go down?

Below is my code, minus CSS.

My HTML

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
    <input type="text" id="inputBoxParam1" name="Param1" placeholder="Param1"/>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="inputBoxParam2" name="Param2" placeholder="Param2" />
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Confirm Details</button>
</form>
```

My JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Prefill the input boxes from parameter values
function getURLParameter(e) {
  return decodeURI((new RegExp(e + "=(.+?)(&|$)").exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1]);
}

if (getURLParameter("Param1").includes("@")) {
  document.getElementById("inputBoxParam1").value = getURLParameter("Param1");
} 
else {
  console.log("No Param1 parameter found.");
}

if (getURLParameter("Param2")) {
  document.getElementById("inputBoxParam2").value = getURLParameter("Param2");
} 
else {
  console.log("No Param2 parameter found.");
}


// Code From GitHub
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/examplescript'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
e.preventDefault()
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
  .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})

</script>
```

I'm only a 17 year old beginner so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to automatically submit the values of the query parameter to your Web Apps when you open the HTML with the URL including the query parameter.

#### Modification points:

- I think that if you want to send the query parameter of `value` and `another` as the keys `param1` and `param2`, `https://example.com/test?param1=value¶m2=another` is required to be modified to `https://example.com/test?param1=value&param2=another`. And, in your javascript, it seems that `param1` is required to include `@`. But, in your query parameter, `param1` is `value`. Please be careful about this.
- In your script, it seems that it is required to click `submit` button. In order to automatically submit the values using the query parameter, the button is not required to be used.
- In your quetion, Google Apps Script is not included. In this answer, I prepare a sample Google Apps Script for achieving your goal.

#### Modified script:

Please set your Web Apps URL to `scriptURL`. In this modification, the button was removed.

##### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
    <input type="text" id="inputBoxParam1" name="Param1" placeholder="Param1"/>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="inputBoxParam2" name="Param2" placeholder="Param2" />
    <br><br>
</form>

<script>
const queryParameters = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search));

if (queryParameters["param1"].includes("@")) {
  document.getElementById("inputBoxParam1").value = queryParameters["param1"];
} else {
  console.log("No Param1 parameter found.");
}

if (queryParameters["param2"]) {
  document.getElementById("inputBoxParam2").value = queryParameters["param2"];
} else {
  console.log("No Param2 parameter found.");
}

const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec'; // Please set your Web Apps URL.

const data = new FormData();
Object.entries(queryParameters).forEach(e => data.append(...e));
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: data})
  .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
</script>
```

##### Google Apps Script side:

In this case, it supposes that the Google Apps Script project is the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this. If your Google Apps Script project is the standalone type, please modify `getActiveSpreadsheet()` to `openById("###spreadsheetId###")`.

```js
const doPost = e => {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const { param1, param2 } = e.parameter;
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.appendRow([param1, param2]); // Or,if you want to add the date to the 1st column, please use sheet.appendRow([new Date(), param1, param2])
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}
```

#### Testing:

In this case, please access your URL of HTML like `https://example.com/test?param1=value@value&param2=another`. By this, the values of `value@value` and `another` are appended to the Spreadsheet.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- If you are not required to show the input tags in the HTML, you can use the following simple HTML.

  ```html
  <script>
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec';

  const queryParameters = [...new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).entries()];
  const data = new FormData();
  queryParameters.forEach(e => data.append(...e));
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: data})
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  </script>
  ```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a clear and concise answer!

Comment: One more question, is there any way we can prevent duplicates from being added to the google sheet? To prevent reload spams?

Comment: @jparko About `This is amazing! Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a clear and concise answer!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @jparko About your new question of `One more question, is there any way we can prevent duplicates from being added to the google sheet? To prevent reload spams?`, I would like to support you. But, this is a new question and this is different from your question. So, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Yes I can cooperate to resolve my new question, I did consider making it a new question, I was just unsure of how to phrase it, and what code would be necessary to post.

Comment: @jparko Thank you for replying. About `Yes I can cooperate to resolve my new question`, in this case, your this question has been resolved. So, please accept this answer. About `I did consider making it a new question, I was just unsure of how to phrase it, and what code would be necessary to post.`, I think that your new question in your reply can be used. When you post a new question, please include your whole script.

Comment: Done! and my new question has been posted :) if you would like to help, find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76197036/20610351

Comment: @jparko Thank you for your response. I will check your new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253527/discussion-between-jparko-and-tanaike).