# Prevent duplicate data in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I currently have 2 parameters being auto submitted to google sheets on page load.

However if the page is reloaded, I receive multiple lines of the same parameters.

I am wondering how I may be able to prevent duplicates inside google sheets.

My code is below :)

JavaScript

```
const queryParameters = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search));

const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/example'


const data = new FormData();
Object.entries(queryParameters).forEach(e => data.append(...e));
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: data})
  .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
```

Google Script Code

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue and your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `I am wondering how I may be able to prevent duplicates inside google sheets.`, in your situation, how about checking the reload? This is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, your Javascript is modified.

```js
if (performance.navigation.type != performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
  const queryParameters = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search));

  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/example';

  const data = new FormData();
  Object.entries(queryParameters).forEach(e => data.append(...e));
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: data })
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
}
```

- In this case, when the HTML page is accessed, `performance.navigation.type != performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD` is true. By this, the script in the if statement is run. When the HTML page is reloaded, `performance.navigation.type != performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD` is false. By this, the script in the if statement is not run. I guessed that this might be your expected result.

#### Reference:

- [Navigation timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API/Navigation_timing)

Comment: Exactly what I was after! Legend!

Comment: Would you mind helping me with this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76206107/remove-url-parameter-data-from-google-sheet