# Remove URL parameter data from google sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm wondering how parameter values from URL can be removed from a google sheet on page load.

This question contains the code in which I am using to ADD the data.

[Send URL Parameters to Google Sheet on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76193499/send-url-parameters-to-google-sheet-on-page-load)

If ONE parameters from the URL is already in the sheet, the entire ROW should be deleted.

Eg.

If the url is
https://example.com/test?email=john@test.com

And the spreadsheet looks like

Name | Email
John | john@test.com

The entire row (in this case) containing John and the email should both be deleted.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When you access `https://example.com/test?email=john@test.com`, you want to delete rows including `john@test.com`.
- When I consider your previous questions, I guess that your Javascript is from my answer. [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76193917) or [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76197082)

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  var email = e.parameter.email; // This is a value from the event object.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var ranges = sheet.getDataRange().createTextFinder(email).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  if (ranges.length == 0) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(`"${email}" was not found.`);
  }
  ranges.reverse().forEach(r => sheet.deleteRow(r.getRow()));
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Rows including "${email}" were deleted.`);
}
```

- When you access `https://example.com/test?email=john@test.com`, my previous scripts request the Web Apps. [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76193917) or [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76197082) And, at the Web Apps side, the above sample script is run. And, the rows including the value of `email` are deleted.
- If you want to use `openById("###")` instead of `getActiveSpreadsheet()`, please modify the above script.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> The second page is simply used to remove data from that same sheet, however this should not have anything to do with the page which adds data.

If your 1st page and your 2nd page are using the same `doPost`, I think that it is required to run the script by a parameter. It becomes as follows.

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const {email, sample} = e.parameter;
  if (sample == "delete") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var ranges = sheet.getDataRange().createTextFinder(email).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
    if (ranges.length == 0) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(`"${email}" was not found.`);
    }
    ranges.reverse().forEach(r => sheet.deleteRow(r.getRow()));
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Rows including "${email}" were deleted.`);
  }

  // When the query parameter doesn't include `sample=delete`, the below script is run. Please set your script of doPost for 1st page.

}
```

#### HTML side:

```html
<script>
if (performance.navigation.type != performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {

  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec'; // Please set your Web Apps URL.

  const queryParameters = [...new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).entries()];
  const data = new FormData();
  queryParameters.forEach(e => data.append(...e));
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: data })
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
}
</script>
```

- In this case, when you access `https://example.com/test?email=john@test.com&sample=delete` with your browser, the script for deleting rows is run. When you access `https://example.com/test?email=john@test.com` with your browser, the script except for the script for deleting rows is run.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a silly question, is this for my website's javascript? or for my web app script?

Comment: Also i should have clarified, this is a new page, so i was not sure if any of the code from your previous answers would be relevant since they were completing the opposite task. If you require more information of what this is being used for i’m happy to explain :) Thank you again for your help, it’s amazing!

Comment: I am also concerned that the other page you helped me make, to add the parameters to the sheet will now stop working, if this code is supposed to go in the app script?

Comment: @jparko Thank you for replying. About `is this for my website's javascript?`, this sample script is for Google Apps Script. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your 3 replies, I cannot understand your current issue using my answer. And also, unfortunately, I cannot know the relationship between your this question and your previous questions. So, can you explain the detail of it? I would like to correctly understand your current issue.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear, for my overall I have 2 pages, one which is sending the data to the sheet from URL parameters, you helped me finish this project in my past question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/76193499/20610351 - The second page is simply used to remove data from that same sheet, however this should not have anything to do with the page which adds data.

Comment: To give you some context, one URL is to add data, and the other is an optional page to visit if someone's data should be removed, if you would like to find out more context I'm happy to speak with you outside of stackoverflow.

Comment: @jparko Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: This is exactly correct! Is it possible to add multiple parameters to this?
So if the URL is https://example.com/test?name=john&email=john@test.com&sample=delete 
Could we make them both delete? Where would I add this extra parameter in the google script?

Comment: @jparko Thank you for replying. About `This is exactly correct!`, I could understand that your issue was resolved. About your new question of `Is it possible to add multiple parameters to this? So if the URL is example.com/… Could we make them both delete? Where would I add this extra parameter in the google script?`, I would like to support you. But, that is different from your question. So, can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this requires a new question since it is the same as my initial question, but your code only got me half way, I have updated my question here, instead.

Comment: @jparko Thank you for replying. About `I'm not sure if this requires a new question since it is the same as my initial question, but your code only got me half way, I have updated my question here, instead.`, please don't change your question. Your new question is different from your initial question. And, your initial question has already been resolved. But, I would like to support you. So, please post it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? Please back your question to the initial question.

Comment: I reverted my question on here and created a new one, find it here :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/76232650/20610351

Comment: Please see this new question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/76329731/20610351