# Remove multiple URL parameter data from google sheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script

My goal is as follows.

When you access https://example.com/test?Name=John&Email=john@test.com&sample=delete, I want to delete the rows which include both John and john@test.com, instead of only checking the email.

Google Script:

```
 const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

 const {email, sample} = e.parameter;
 if (sample == "delete") {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
   var ranges = sheet.getDataRange().createTextFinder(email).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
   if (ranges.length == 0) {
     return ContentService.createTextOutput(`"${email}" was not found.`);
   }
   ranges.reverse().forEach(r => sheet.deleteRow(r.getRow()));
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Rows including "${email}" were deleted.`);
 }

 // When the query parameter doesn't include `sample=delete`, the below script is run. Please set your script of doPost for 1st page.

}
```

Javascript:

````
if (performance.navigation.type != performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {

  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec'; // Please set your Web Apps URL.

  const queryParameters = [...new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).entries()];
  const data = new FormData();
  queryParameters.forEach(e => data.append(...e));
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: data })
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
}
</script> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your URL of `https://example.com/test?Name=John&Email=john@test.com&sample=delete`, I understood that the key names are `Name`, `Email`, and `sample`. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, Google Apps Script is modified.

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const { Name, Email, sample } = e.parameter;
  if (sample == "delete") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var ranges = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = ranges.getValues().filter(r => ![Name, Email].every(e => r.includes(e)));
    if (ranges.length == 0) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(`"${email}" was not found.`);
    }
    ranges.clearContent().offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Rows including "${Email}" were deleted.`);
  }

  // When the query parameter doesn't include `sample=delete`, the following script is run. Please set your script of doPost for 1st page.

}
```

- When `https://example.com/test?Name=John&Email=john@test.com&sample=delete` is used, the rows of `Name=John` and `Email=john@test.com` are deleted.
- If you want to use `https://example.com/test?name=John&email=john@test.com&sample=delete`, please modify `Name` and `Email` to `name` and `email`, respectively.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".