# Don't add data if its already in google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently I have parameters being added to my google sheet on page load.

The URL looks like https://example.com/page?Name=John&Email=john@gmail.com

I'm wondering how I can stop this data being added a second time if people visit this URL again.

I currently stop a resubmission on page reload, but this doesn't stop a user if the URL is placed in a new tab, or opened on another device.

Is there a way to check if the same parameters are already in the sheet, and stop it being added if it is.

Javascript:

```
if (performance.navigation.type != performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
  const queryParameters = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search));

  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/script/exec';

  const data = new FormData();
  Object.entries(queryParameters).forEach(e => data.append(...e));
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: data })
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
}
```

Google Script

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {

  const { Name, Email, sample } = e.parameter;
  if (sample == "delete") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var ranges = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = ranges.getValues().filter(r => ![Name, Email].every(e => r.includes(e)));
    if (ranges.length == 0) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(`"${email}" was not found.`);
    }
    ranges.clearContent().offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(`Rows including "${Email}" were deleted.`);
  }


  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

I hope that makes sense, I am happy to clarify.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
try {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)
```

#### To:

```
try {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => [Name, Email].every(e => r.includes(e)));
  if (values.length > 0) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Values were not appended.");
  }
```

- By this modification, when the values of `Name` and `Email` are existing, the script is stopped.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Exactly what I was after!